How to prepare differently for a freelance interview vs a full time employee interview?
I am trying to become a freelancer or a contractor in backend/data engineering/algorithm development, working remotely.
My entire professional life has been full time work, either from the office, or hybrid.
I would like to prepare for interviews and assume there will be a difference in how they work - I assume it will be hire faster-fire faster mentality, but would like to hear from people who actually do it or from people who hire for such positions.

The Original TWP Post where some user suggested to ask it here as well

The interview process for a freelancer tends to be a 'fast track' version of the one for an employee.
If a recruiter is involved, there will probably be a relatively short talk (hardly an actual interview) with the recruiter, so they feel confident sending you onward to the client.
The client interview is often short (30 - 60 minutes), is very project-centric, almost never involves HR and does not consist of several rounds with a changing group of people.
Almost all questions are technical, allowing you to elaborate on previous relevant experience. At times, there may be 'softer' questions regarding how you react to adversity, unclear requirements and difficult people. This may be a sign of a somewhat challenging working environment.
The interviewer is probably the project manager and/or a senior professional; at times when the project manager is technical enough, they might be the sole interviewer. The recruiter might participate in the interview, but merely as an observer. It seems some recruiters prefer participating - and some clients prefer they do not, as they rarely add any value at that stage. Whether they participate is out of my hands, so I tend to not care.
As a freelancer, I would like to know which exact role is expected of me, which other roles are adequately covered (so I won't end up in them) and what the current challenges are. This line of questioning will be more direct than an employee would (or should?) ask - but is necessary to determine whether the project is a good fit. In addition, I personally find it beneficial to immediately demonstrate that I am a freelancer and not an employee.

How do you fail such an interview? When the process is long, there is ample opportunity to fail. But if the interview is very quick, how does the company know if you are good for them or not?

@Gulzar: The client could find you not a good fit for many reasons: Maybe you prefer working on creating new things as opposed to mere maintenance. Maybe you prefer working on one task rather than several. Maybe you prefer mostly remote. The main point is that freelancers are most often easier to hire and fire, allowing for the interview to be less rigorous - as being on-the-job will quickly reveal a bad match, which may then lead to a quick termination

This answer over at The Workplace is the most helpful, it reads in part:

" ... you might hire a developer who has no experience in your specific language/tool/framework, because a good developer can easily pick that up.
... the interview for a freelancer is much more focused on their actual skills and abilities today, and whether they know the specific tools and technologies needed to hit the ground running.".
Source: "What are the differences between interviews for freelance vs. full time positions?" by user "Gh0stFish"

But the answer really depends on the company hiring.
I may live in the big city but, people tend to know by your confidence and ability to answer specific questions quickly and in a manner understandable to them what their gut tells them, so either by resume or portfolio the interview is usually just getting a look at you; assuming your resume/portfolio is excellent.
I'm not saying that's a good way to hire, but really who is more qualified - them or you. If it's you then you'll assess the situation quickly and shift gears like a pro. If it is they who are much more qualified then asking about things that aren't on your resume/portfolio is more either one-upmanship or to find out how much it will cost without asking you; because they know from the last several people they spoke with were they stand.
In either case, employee or freelance, they want to know how much they will have to do; and if you aren't first, how much they'll have to pay. They may know correctly what they want, or there may easily be a whole lot more required than they mention. With an employee they can just pile on another task you are responsible for, with a freelancer and a well written contract they know that changes are something that costs extra.
The best way to control the situation is from your end.

Have the best possible resume/portfolio that showcases your education and work experience in specific areas; and for the resume your title, who you reported to, is important.

When being hired as an employee it's tough to explain that you'll have to take time off from work to interview, and you've done that a suspicious number of times already. Over the phone first interviews outside of working hours are great, as long as they don't make it too short and try to rope you into coming in.
As a freelancer you should be charging travel time and by the hour. You want to go there and bill for the time, not chat on the phone for free. If you are not swamped and can both set aside the time to visit and charge for it there's no loss like there is for a looky-loo interview.

An employee is more constrained by other people's wages, both inside the company and potential new hires. A freelancer can charge what they like if they're extremely busy, if they aren't busy they still don't need to bid low, nor does that necessarily guarantee winning the bid. Stay out of races to the bottom.

The leverage (how you can act, what you can charge, what you must do) is usually lower for employees, but it's not always the case. For a freelancer they might ask if terms can be different from where you are coming from (prior to having mutual terms) but they probably won't try to get too far astray once you've declined something; and only not later if you hold the keys.
For the potential employee the employer will usually have pre-concieved ideas about a mold into which you must fit, if you're early in the hiring list. As time goes by and the works not being done, money lost, the employer may realize that they must shed some of their ideas and take whoever isn't clearly unsuitable. That's why at some places there's a bunch of people who were not well interviewed, and only had recommendations and work history from companies closed long ago.


As a start-up you'll be best accumulating a bunch of simple short jobs, they can be good advertising and may lead to future freelance work. Once you have a great portfolio and a number of places willing to recommend you, either only to their friends or preferably publically (on your website), then you'll be more hired on reputation than on reinventing the wheel (lengthy interviews) at each employer/customer.
Look it this way, when you interviewed for a job if was often the place assumed or didn't know if you could do the job; they questioned, sometimes at length.
While with freelance, or when you work somewhere as an employee and the call is directed to you (essentially the company is the freelancer and you are the subcontractor), they usually ask if you can do X and accept your yes or no; unless they've had a lot of problems with prior people, or they know that the work is complex and has particular requirements.
It's like you go somewhere and they've put up a new sign, and you are thinking I wouldn't do that; someone must have, or enough people have, or the sign wouldn't be newly posted.
With freelancing it's important to have things to do when it's not busy, as an employee you might want to not be too busy when there's things to do; but not so slack you get let go.

Not chatting for free makes no sense to me. It isn't a chat-for-free; it is a sales call. I want that call, not them.

@gulzar, that's what it says; maybe re-read that.

Generally speaking, there really isn't any difference in the interviews. The difference comes in the expectations between an employee and a contractor.
There are two types of contractors: people who fill a "full time equivalent" position and those who do "project work".
With the "full time equivalent", the client company may provide equipment and expect you to bill for 40 hours per week. They may expect you to bill them for time spent on things like reading and answering emails.
With project work, the client may expect you to have your own equipment, your own tools, and even E&O insurance. "Overhead" such as email reading, checking these forums, learning new technologies, etc. is often your cost and not billed to the client especially when you have multiple clients.
I have one client where the other contractor expected them to provide the tools and equipment, and I expected that I was to provide my own. I heard multiple times from that client that they were upset with the other contractor specifically about this issue.
